# HTML elements in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, anchor

```
HtmlAnchor[] anchorToConvert = new HtmlAnchor[]{
    clickHere,
leavePage};

Button[] buttonToConvert = new Button[]{
    login,
register};

i = 0;
for (i = 0; i &lt; anchorToConvert.Length; i++)
{
    DataRow[] result = ds.Tables[0].Select("htmlControl LIKE '" + anchorToConvert[i].ID.ToString() + "'");

    if (result.Length &gt; 0)
    {
        anchorToConvert[i].InnerHtml = result[0]["phrase"].ToString();
    }
}
i = 0;
for (i = 0; i &lt; buttonToConvert.Length; i++)
{
    DataRow[] result = ds.Tables[0].Select("htmlControl LIKE '" + buttonToConvert[i].ID.ToString() + "'");

    if (result.Length &gt; 0)
    {
        buttonToConvert[i].Text = result[0]["phrase"].ToString();
    }
}
```

I have two arrays of html elements i need to loop through, and use the elements id attribute to select content from a database. Rather than having to create two arrays and loop through them individually, is there someway i can make a more generic array that can contain both buttons and anchors?

Comment: How familiar with C# are you? You can create a class that has two fields `HtmlAnchor` and `Button` and then just make an array of that class.

Comment: i have only been using it for 2 weeks....having to convert a site from php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a list and check the type of the control in the list when you're looping through:

```
List<Control> ctrl = new List<Control>();
HtmlAnchor anchor = new HtmlAnchor();
anchor.ID = "myAnchor";
ctrl.Add(anchor);

Button btn = new Button();
btn.ID = "MyBtn";

ctrl.Add(btn);

foreach (Control c in ctrl.ToList())
{
    if (c is Button)
    {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `HtmlAnchor` and `Button` inherit from [`Web.UI.Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.aspx) (though not directly).

If that is the type of the array, both of these types (`HtmlAnchor` and `Button`) can be assign to the array.